# Splitting code in to multiple files for easier management

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using jQuery to write an online application, that started off with a couple of lines of code, and have quickly now become over a 1000 lines.

My code's structure is simple. I have a window.load which wraps my javascript, and inside it I start adding my click event handlers, and the various functions that makeup my application.

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // Code goes here...
});
```

My code functions can definitely be grouped into categories; e.g. 5 functions perform animation, 12 are event handlers, etc.

I would like to group the functions in their own js files, and import them individually. I can later use my CMS engine to concatenate and compress the files on the fly.

What is the best way in doing so. I am thinking that maybe I can give some of my functions their own namespace for further clarity; e.g. all animation functions are prefixed with ANIMATION - ANIMATION.moveDiv1(), ANIMATION.moveDiv2, MYEVENT.div1Clicked, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally stick all related items into their own file, with a namespace that matches the file for readability sake.

An example file could look like:

Example.js

```
var Animation = {}; // create the namespace-like object
Animation.moveDiv1 = function() {...};
Animation.moveDiv2 = function() {...};
```

There's really a lot of ways to do this.  Speaking of compression, there are some nice tools that you can use to compress things.  Check out [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Modularity is a good goal with Javascript, but I would say the next level would be to actually use some Javascript OO techniques.  If your app is simple enough, you can probably do without it though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code files should mirror your classes.
2. Your classes should follow principles of good OO design.

In terms of load-time within the browser, kekoav and knut have the right idea - just use YUI or another script compressor/minifier (and optionally an obfuscator), combine them into a single file and load them all from a single script include directive.

I'd also have a look at JS the prototype property of your classes - if they're getting large and you're creating multiple instances of them, you'll start to see significant performance gains by putting your public (and optionally, private/privileged) methods into the class prototype.

You should definitely be using fully-qualified namespaces for your classes, either using Microsoft's Type.registerNamespace if you're using their AJAX solution, by declaring your own namespace functions as per kekoav's post, or using a squillion other similar approaches that Google will offer.

Answer (score 0):

Good idea from a standpoint of application management, bad idea from the standpoint of loading time. The browser has to load all those little scripts synchronously, therefore taking more time for each additional script you want to load. That's not including the main jQuery library script, the jQuery UI and whatever else you plan on having in your document. Test both premises: abstracting functions out into their own individual scripts and load them vs. one big script that only requires one call to load. Take it a step further and minify the "one big script", one more step and make sure it's served as a compressed file.

Comment: I guess you missed the part about "I can later use my CMS engine to concatenate and compress the files on the fly".

Answer (score 0):

You may split the JavaScript files into classes when you are developing, but you should combine your scripts, and minimize them in a production environment. Please take a look at [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) for more information.